# Is rabbitmq bidirectional?

Tags: rabbitmq

Producer sends messages rabbitmq, and the consumer receives messages from rabbitmq, then consumer send messages back to producer via rabbitmq.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it just acknowledge consumer got message?

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to implement an RPC type of system, or do you just want to know how to send messages in both directions?

The basic pipe is unidirectional.  You cannot send messages from the consumer to the producer through the same queue that the consumer received messages from the producer.

If you want send messages the other way, your consumer will need to be a producer as well, and your producer will need to be a consumer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible,  but the producer will have to listen to a queue as well on which the client will publish/produce... ,  you can send the queueName/routingkey(of the producer) in the first msg sent from producer to client.. the client then after recieving the msg with the routingkey inside can send msg to original producer

Answer (score 0):

Producer needs another queue to get the response back from Consumer, so called callback queue. Producer can send request with reply_to and correlation_id. Then, Consumer can utilize reply_to as the routing key to point to the correct callback queue and Producer can dequeue the callback queue and match the correlation_id.